# Textbox character validation

Tags: javascript, validation, input, textbox

I am taking a textbox value as a file name to store a file and that input comes from the end users. So I need validate that `"\/:*?"<>|"` these characters are not present in the input value since file name can not contain those special character. How I can do this using javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// val - is your value
if (/[\/:*?"<>|]/.test(val)) {
    alert('invalid!');
    // ... prevent form from being sent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = 'test"';
if(/[\/:*?"<>|]/.test(input)){
    alert('Contains a special char');
} else{
    alert("It's clean!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expression to test it

```
var regex = /(\\)|(\/)|(\?)/; // and so on

var input = document.forms[0].files.value;
if (regex.test(input)) {
  // the charecter are present;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var str="your_file_name";

if (/^[^`\\\-/\:_{}\*\?\"\<\>\|\.]+(\.[^\\\/\:\*\?\"\<\>\|\.]+)+$/.test(str)) { 

 alert("valid file name");

 }
```